# How to resolve "questionmarks" when parsing a dtd validated XML document via Java SAXParser?

Tags: java, xml, sax, dtd

I am wondering why my `SaxParser` seems not to be able to resolve certain entities defined in an external dtd file. I am processing a huge xml file which has the following header. So the input is (heavily reduced :-)):

```
// myxml.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE authors SYSTEM "mydtd.dtd">
<authors>
    <author>
        Bal&aacute;zs
    </author>
</authors>
```

And this is the incorrect output:

```
Bal
?zs
```

Obviousely `&aacute;` was not resolved!

This is how I have set up the parser:

```
// MySaxParser.java

public class MySaxParser extends DefaultHandler {

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if ("author".equals(currentTag)) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(Arrays.copyOfRange(ch, start, start + length)));
    }
}

static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, false);
    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    spf.setValidating(true); // From what I understood from the API this combined
                             // with '<!DOCTYPE mydtd SYSTEM "mydtd.dtd">' from
                             // the file myxml.xml should do the trick. What do I miss?

    SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(new SAXLocalNameCount());
    xmlReader.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler(System.err));

    xmlReader.parse("file:/path/to/myxml.xml");
}
}
```

What do I miss? Do I somehow have to do more than `spf.setValidating(true)` to make the parser aware of the dtd defined in the xml file header?

I should mention that the dtd and xml are syntactically and semantically correct. The dtd contains `<!ENTITY aacute  "&#225;" ><!-- small a, acute accent -->` as a mapping for resolving. I donwloaded the files from a trusted source, so the error has to be in my Code.

**Update:**

As @eckes suggested, I printed the int values of the characters as they are passed into the method `characters` via

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if ("author".equals(currentTag)) {
        for (int i = start; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ch[i] + " - " + Character.getNumericValue(ch[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

The console output was:

```
B - 11
a - 10
l - 21
? - -1
z - 35
s - 28
```

The -1 indicates that something went wrong before the event `characters` was even fired, doesn't it?

My ErrorHandler:

```
package com.hw;

import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    private PrintStream out;

    MyErrorHandler(PrintStream out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    private String getParseExceptionInfo(SAXParseException spe) {
        String systemId = spe.getSystemId();

        if (systemId == null) {
            systemId = "null";
        }

        String info = "URI=" + systemId + " Line=" + spe.getLineNumber() + ": "
                + spe.getMessage();

        return info;
    }

    public void warning(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        out.println("Warning: " + getParseExceptionInfo(spe));
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        String message = "Error: " + getParseExceptionInfo(spe);
        throw new SAXException(message);
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        String message = "Fatal Error: " + getParseExceptionInfo(spe);
        throw new SAXException(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: The element name (here `dtd`) in the `<!DOCTYPE dtd ` should match the name of the root-level element in the XML, is this correct in your real XML?

Comment: @IanRoberts, yes it is, I typed it wrong, will fix that immediately.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not an encoding problem?

Comment: @Hannes, the encoding is defined in the header of the xml file for the Parser to derive from: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`. Do you mean the encoding of my sysout could be another one as "ISO-8859-1"?

Comment: I think @Hannes is correct you should check one more time about sysout.

Comment: "?" looks like the replacement char for encoders, so I think the entity was actually resolved but could not be represented in your encoding. Why dont you print out the int value for the char instead of the string.

Comment: @eckes, I added the mapping from char to int as suggested. For the character in question -1 is returned.

Comment: @Aufwind yes it looks like the encoder of the Reader is the problem. However I am not exactly sure why, the encoding should not apply to entities. Is the error handler not printing anything? Did you try to add the "&#225;" directly into the test file?

Comment: @eckes, putting "&#225;" directly into the xml file yields `B - 11, a - 10, l - 21, ? - -1`. As you can see the line with the questionmark is the last one printed - in contrast for the output I added above in my question. An expcetion is not thrown. I posted my error handler above, too to make it possible to uncover errors there, too.

Comment: @Aufwind hm strange. It seems to deliver different callbacks in that case?

Comment: @eckes, yes, it simply stops after the character in question if I add `&#225;` directly to the file - but without throwing an exception. Currently I am trying to make sense of the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482494/howto-let-the-sax-parser-determine-the-encoding-from-the-xml-declaration But otherwise I am totally out of ideas. :-)

Comment: which SAX parser are you using?

Comment: @forty-two, I am using `import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser; import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;`

Comment: @Aufwind Yes, I can see that, but what implementation do you pick up. Print the full name of the actual SAXParser instance.

Comment: @forty-two, sorry, I should have known you are asking for the implementation. Here is what a sysout prints for my sax parser instance: `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl@2382600f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most certainly have a problem with the output encoding, i.e. the console or whatever that is receiving your output cannot correctly handle UTF-16 (which is the native java encoding).

And, you are also being tricked by the `Characters#getNumericValue()` method into thinking that you have an input or parser encoding problem. The `getNumericValue()` tries to interpret the character as something representing a number, not the actual code point value or anything such. As the documentation states, if you give the roman numeral fifty, Ⅼ (U+216C), the method would print `50`.

Try replacing the line:

```
System.out.println(ch[i] + " - " + Character.getNumericValue(ch[i]));
        System.out.println(ch[i] + " - " + Character.getNumericValue(ch[i]));
```

with

```
System.out.println(ch[i] + " - " + Integer.toHexString((int) ch[i]));
```

and you'll probably see that it prints

```
? - e1
```

Now, how to fix the ouput encoding problem: I cannot help you there unless you give us more details.

**Update**

You can set the eclipse console encoding in

```
Run Configurations --> Common
```

or in the JDK/JRE using the

```
-Dfile.encoding
```

property (not 100% sure on this one).

Comment: you were right, I made the suggested change and it yielded what you expected. What do you need to know, to help me fix the output encoding problem? Here is a first bunch of information I think it might be relevant. I assume the `char` array `ch` contains characters encoded in `"ISO-8859-1"`, right? I am currently on a Mac using Eclipse indigo. A `System.out.println("Default Encoding = " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));`yielded `US-ASCII`.

Comment: char[] does not have different encodings (it is always UTF16).